# limit points and sets

Tags: real-analysis

For sets *E* and *F*, how do we show that if *E* $\subset$ *F* and *F* is closed (i.e. *F* contains all of its limit points or *F'* $\subset$ F, where *F'* denotes the set of limit points of *F*), then *E'* $\subset$ *F'* (and hence *E'* $\subset$ *F* )?

Is it obvious that if *F* contains all of its limit points and *E* is a subset of *F*, then *F* contains all of the limit points of *E*?

Comment: Note: if E is a subset of  F then any limit point of E is a limit point of F and as F is closed is therefore in F.

Comment: I reasoned that every limit point of E is a limit point of F because any neighborhood (or ball) that contains an element of E contains an element of F (because E is a subset of F).

Answer (score 0):

$E\subset F$ implies that if $x=lim x_n, x_n\in E, x\in F'$ since  $x_n\in E\subset F$ implies that $x_n\in F$ so $x\in F'$ and  $E'\subset F'=F$.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it obvious that if F contains all of its limit points and E is a subset of F, then F contains all of the limit points of E?"

Well, I don't know about "obvious" but it becomes pretty clear by definition.

Let $g$ be a limit point of $E$ then every neighborhood of $g$ contains a point of $E \subset F$ not equal to $g$.  So every limit point of $E$ contains a point of $F$ not equal to $g$.  So $g$ is a limit point of $F$.  So...

If $E \subset F$ then limit_points($E$) $\subset$ limit_points($F$).

So if $F$ is closed, then limit_points($E$) $\cup E = \overline {E} \subset F$.